# Apresentar nome de usuário logado em tela

Tags: php

Olá! Na página restrita do meu site, precisa apresentar o nome do usuário logado, o mesmo ocorre no formulário que é exibido. Mas notei que não está aparecendo, nem no "Olá" e nem no formulário. Analisei o código e não consegui encontrar nada diferente do que eu havia deixado antes.
Gostaria de uma ajudinha pra identificar o possível erro do porque não apresentar. :)

É assim que está na página restrita para buscar e apresentar o nome do usuário em tela:

```
Olá, <p id="usuario"></p>
<script>document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("usuario");</script>
```

E assim que está no código de verificar login, onde eu busco pelas i'ds apresentadas no banco de dados:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'config.php';
    ini_set('display_errors',true);
    ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if ( isset( $_POST ) && ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
        $dados_usuario = $_POST;
    } else {
        $dados_usuario = $_SESSION;
    }
    $validacao = login($dados_usuario['usuario'], $dados_usuario['password']);
    if(isset($dados_usuario)){
        if ($validacao) {
            $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
            $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] = $validacao->user_name;
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $validacao->user;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $validacao->user_id;
            $_SESSION['nom_clin']= $validacao->nom_clin;
            ?><script>localStorage.setItem("usuario", "<?php echo $validacao->usuario?>");</script><?php
  }
       exit;
        }
     else {
         echo 'Login e Senha incorretos. Favor voltar a página e tentar novamente.';
        // Continua deslogado
        $_SESSION['logado'] = false;
        // Preenche o erro para o usuário
        $_SESSION['login_erro'] = 'Usuário ou senha inválidos';
        //session_destroy();
        //header("Location: restrito.php");
        //exit;

    }

        function login($login, $senha)
        {

            try {
                $sql = "SELECT cod_clin, user, user_name, user_id, nom_clin FROM usuarios WHERE user_id='$login' AND user_password='$senha' LIMIT 1";
                $conn = getConexao();
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                return $row;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e;
                return false;
            }
        }
?>
```

E as id's conferem com as do banco de dados.

Comment: Quais são as propriedades retornadas pela função `login($dados_usuario['usuario'], $dados_usuario['password'])`? Pois, em um momento você usa `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $validacao->user;` e em outro você usa `<?php echo $validacao->usuario?>`. Pode ser que a propriedade `$validacao->usuario` não exista e sim `$validacao->user`.

Comment: Você testou colocando o `;` como mencionei em minha resposta ? Onde estão declaradas as varáveis `$login e $senha` presente em sua querie ?

Comment: @MagicHat Testei sim, e não influenciou em nada. Há uns 2 meses, a apresentação do nome do usuário aparecia normalmente sem nenhum problema. E semana passada fui mexer nos arquivos do site e foi onde eu vi que não apresenta mais.

Comment: Tá e as variáveis ?

Comment: @MagicHat Na linha " function login($login, $senha)        {"

Comment: Eu sei que parece um detalhe mas a falta dos ";"  pode causar grande dor de cabeça nos códigos eu mesmo já passei maus bocados com isso e a olhar o código falta um ";" depois de: "<?php echo $validacao->usuario". Já deu um var_dump($_SESSION['nome_da_sessao']) para saber se está tudo certo?

Answer (score 2):

**PHP SESSION**

Você tem armazenado o nome do usuário no SESSION então basta chamá-lo no código, muda ele da seguinte forma:

```
Olá, <p id="usuario"><?php echo $_SESSION['nome_usuario']; ?></p>
// Pode remover o Script
```

Para acessar os dados do **SESSION** é importante iniciar a Sessão, utitlizando `session_start()`, da seguinte forma:

```
<?php session_start(); // é possível inicializar o SESSION logo no início do arquivo.
```

Comment: @InezBoldrin bom dia, é como o Thiago te mencionou, como se trata de uma váriavel global você pode utiliza-la em qualquer parte do projeto bastando apenas chamar a variável.

Comment: Thiago, fiz dessa forma que você colocou e não apresentou nada.
O session_start já havia sido colocado antes, que também não estava apresentando nome nenhum em tela.

Comment: Logo Após o `session_start()` faz um `print_r($_SESSION);` e verifica se tem algo salvo na sessão, se estiver vazia verifica se tu iniciou a sessão no arquvio onde tu faz a validação.

Comment: No arquivo que verifica o login do usuário já está com o session_start. Coloquei o print e abri o consola, está em branco.

Comment: o `session_start();` é a primeira coisa na página? Coloca como primeira coisa. Mais um teste, faz um `echo $validacao->user_name;` logo antes de colocar essa variável pra dentro da sessão e verifica se ela não está em branco!

Comment: Thiago, depois que eu coloquei o print e atualizei a página (agora a pouco, novamente), apresentou no inicio da página o seguinte "Array()".
O que poderia ser?

Comment: `$_SESSION` é um Array() e está vazio, mas isso é progresso, está usando **print_r**? Tem que ser print_r!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54003/discussion-between-thiago-santos-and-inez-boldrin).

Answer (score 1):

Não esqueça de iniciar a sessão :

```
$validacao = login($dados_usuario['usuario'], $dados_usuario['password']);
if(isset($dados_usuario))
{    if($validacao)
     {    session_start();
          //continue
```

E então você pode chamá-lo como na resposta do Thiago...

```
Olá, <p id="usuario"><?php echo $_SESSION['nome_usuario']; ?></p>
```

Outro detalhe é que do jeito que está na sua pergunta

```
<?php echo $validacao->usuario?>
```

Está faltando um `;`, então se for fazer com js começa por alterar para :

```
<?php echo $validacao->usuario;?>
------------------------------^
```

Comment: Essa validação eu já tenho no arquivo verifica_login.php.
Quando coloquei no arquivo da restrito.php apresentou a página em branco.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o bloco do código anterior relevante a parte de sessão....

Comment: A linha que possui o "Olá" é onde eu quero que apareça o nome do usuário em tela.
Na linha que tem $validacao é onde está o código do verifica_login (pra verificar usuário e senha), onde as mesmas id's conferem com as que estão no banco de dados.

Comment: Bom, o que acontece é o seguinte, você possui um código anterior que pode influenciar o comportamento do que está sendo proposto na pergunta, então fica mais fácil de resolver se postar esses códigos tmb...

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um método HTTP request para o código retornar um JSON contendo todos os dados que você quer utilizar, e passar para o Javascript utilizando o Jquery.

```
$.getJSON("DadosDoUsuario.php").
done(function (dados) {
$("#nomedadiv").html("Olá "+dados.NOMEUSUARIO);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Seguindo a query `$sql = "SELECT cod_clin, user, user_name, user_id, nom_clin FROM usuarios WHERE user_id='$login' AND user_password='$senha' LIMIT 1";` o `PDO` irá lhe retornar as seguintes propriedades: `cod_clin`, `user`, `user_name`, `user_id`, `nom_clin`.

```
object(stdClass) {
    public $cod_clin;
    public $user;
    public $user_name;
    public $user_id;
    public $nom_clin;
}
```

Ou seja, ao chamar `$validacao->usuario` irá retornar que a propriedade `usuario` não foi definida, quebrando a aplicação. Experimente chamar `$validacao->user`

Comment: Troquei o `$validacao->usuario` por  `$validacao->user` e também não apresentou em tela o usuário.

Comment: Dessas colunas `cod_clin, user, user_name, user_id, nom_clin`, qual retorna o nome do usuário?

Comment: É o  `user` mesmo que retorna.

Comment: Faz um `var_dump($validacao);` apos `$validacao = login($dados_usuario['usuario'], $dados_usuario['password']);` e vê se está lhe retornando os dados do usuário. Se puder compartilha o retorno.